# If $y$ limit point then prove that $\overline{X-\{y\}}=X$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ a metric and $y\in X$ if $y$ limit point of $X$

prove $\overline{X-\{y\}}=X$

Could someone lend me a hand to start this one off?

**Edit from comments:**

I tried the following: since $y$ is a limit point, there is a sequence $\{y_n\}_n$ from $X\setminus\{y\}$ with $y_n\to y$.  So $y\in\overline{X\setminus\{y\}}$.

Since $X\setminus\{y\}\subseteq\overline{X\setminus\{y\}}\subseteq X$, I just need to show that the right-hand containment is equality.  And that follows from what I showed above, right?

Is this a good proof?

Comment: What have you tried? What definitions are you aware of?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani I am aware of all the definitions, So i tried with a sequence $(y_n)$ which converges to y since its  limit point and because $(y_n) \in X-\{y\}$ $\implies y \in \overline{X-\{y\}}$

Comment: So when you want to show that two sets are equal, you wish to show each is a subset of the other. Do you know that a set is always contained in its closure? Do you see what more you have to show?

Comment: sorry for the many edits thats what i wanted to type

Comment: Do you see that you already have the inclusion $$X - \{y\} \subset \overline{X - \{y\}} \subset X.$$ To show the last to be an equality, there's only one point that you need to consider being in the closure. Which point is it? Can you show that is indeed in the closure?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani isnt it what i proved above? i proved that y is in the closure

Comment: Yes, you have done. With that, you have answered your own question.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani perfect thanks for the guidance!

Comment: To close this question (i.e., for you to accept an answer and move it out of the unanswered queue), I have added an alternate idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already answered it in the comments in one way, here's another way to prove it, using the definitions that avoid sequences:

Recall the following for set $x \in X$ and $Y \subset X$:

1. $x$ is a limit point of $Y$ iff $(B_r(x) \setminus \{x\}) \cap Y \neq \varnothing$ for all $r > 0$.
2. $x \in \overline{Y}$ iff $B_r(x) \cap Y \neq \varnothing$ for all $r > 0$.

In particular, if $x \notin Y$, then $x$ is a limit point of $Y$ iff $x$ is in the closure of $Y$.
In our case, we have $Y = X - \{y\}$ and $x = y$. Clearly, $y \notin Y$ and thus, it follows that $y \in \overline{X - \{y\}}$. From this, the desired equality follows.